# Wireless very slow after operating system change

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I've been a long time Windows user, last it was Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit and I'm now running Linux Mint 11 64bit.

However if on Windows I was able to get to a download speed of 3.2MB/s then on Mint I can barely get to 200KB/s and I have a feeling it's because Mint doesn't know which wireless driver to use on my machine.

I have Lenovo Thinkpad E520. Being new to Linux, I have no idea how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem (and asked about it on the same site :-) ) when switching to mint from another Linux distribution.
Mint uses the Ubuntu package base which, in my experience, has the best wireless drivers of any Linux distro. You're using Mint 11 which is based on Ubuntu 11.04. I'd recommend going back to Mint 9 which is based on Ubuntu 10.04, the current LTS.

Comment: I'm quite sure there's a driver for my machine that works exactly like the Windows one or almost like it, I just don't know how do know what to look for, where do get it and how to install and use it. If nothing seems to work I just have to go back to Windows because this speed is just way too slow. I have tried 10x Ubuntu LTS, that didn't recognize that I have Wifi what-so-ever.

Comment: Oh well. In that case, look for your device's driver on the following list. Instructions are provided there. http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices

Comment: Already stuck at the first part where writing "lspci -vnn | grep 14e4" to terminal returns nothing. Nothing at all.

Comment: @wabbble that page is for Broadcom cards. 14e4 is Broadcom's PCI Vendor ID. Getting no results probably means your Lenovo's wireless card isn't from Broadcom.